# javascript : how to send request in restful

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

Hello I want to ask you something
how do I send a request to the webservice (restful) if the parameters which I will send more than one parameter?

**edit:**

```
this.sendRequest = function(){
   var url="http://localhost:8081/inlinetrans/";

   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var oriText ="";
   var stemText ="";
   var folText ="";

   client.open("PUT", url, false);

   client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
   client.send(oriText,stemText,folText);


   if (client.status == 200){
   client.responseText;
   }
   else{
    client.statusText;
   }

  }
```

client.send --> contents parameters which i want send to server

Comment: The same way you send requests normally, you just add more parameters. Please show us some more concrete code and a more concrete problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are making a request for data, you should use a GET request. Any parameters required to fetch the correct data should be passed in the query string:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8081/inlinetrans?key1=value1&key2=value2...';
client.open("GET", url, true);
client.send(null);
```

If on the other hand you want to **send** data to the server, you should use a POST request:

```
var data = ....
client.open("POST", url, true);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
client.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
client.send("data=" + encodeURIComponent(data));
```

Typically `data` would be a JSON string. Of course, all of this depends on the API of the service. Without knowing these details, I cannot help beyond the typical example above.

Comment: Is there more documentation for this somewhere?

Comment: Note that for some reason by doing `client.send(null);` with `GET` method you may get 2 requests done in Chrome (!). Changing the call to `client.send();` should fix that.